# AWS Neptune Jupyter Gremlin Queries not able to display a visualization of the graph?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, gremlin, amazon-neptune, graph-visualization

So I have been working on setting up and querying a Neptune graph database with success so far, but I have been unable to get the graph visualization working.

[Visualization Tutorial](https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/blob/main/src/graph_notebook/notebooks/02-Visualization/Blog%20Workbench%20Visualization.ipynb)

For example, the %seed line magic function does not bring up an interactive dropdown to create a sample database but instead returns text output.

[Seed Text Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdwnH.png)

Running a query on my already existing database will give a console output but no option to view a graph and the query metadata is simply printed to text as well. I've tried many other specific queries and cell magic hints to no avail.

[Existing Query (some data omitted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gneWT.png)

The notebook and IPython are both up to date.

```
%graph_notebook_version
2.1.4

IPython.__version__
'7.16.1'
```

Any help on getting the visualization working would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi there - a couple of questions - are you using (1) Jupyter or Jupyter Labs and (2) do you see a menu item at the top of the notebooks that says Neptune? Also, the 3.0 version of the notebooks was just release. You may want to update to that level. It has lots of new features and sample notebook content. Currently you need to use Jupyter while running these notebooks and not Jupyter Labs

Comment: I am primarily working through Jupyter Labs, I do not see a menu item at the top that says Neptune however (this is on Jupyter or Jupyter labs). I was also not aware of the 3.0 update, I've only seen that the graphical visualization came out last year sometime. Thank you for the Jupyter vs Jupyter Labs tip I'll check it out!

Comment: Ok quick update, I ran it through Jupypter instead of labs and got something different! It now includes the Query Metadata as its own tab as expected but is still missing a graph component. Is it possible that the test queries I posted originally is just not in a format suitable to being graphed?

Comment: To see a diagram you will want to have something like `g.V().outE().inV().path()` so that there is a vertex after the edge to render. I would definitely recommend upgrading to the latest release also as it is much easier to get nice looking visuals. In this case the hint would need to be `v,oute,inv`

Comment: The Air-Routes-Gremlin sample notebook has a section at the top showing all the ways to get a visualization. As I mentioned, if possible upgrade to the latest graph-notebook version as it makes creating visuals a lot easier. You can do this without needing to update your Neptune cluster.

Comment: Wow this has been incredibly incredibly helpful! I wish I had asked earlier thank you so much. I finally got the query I initially was working with to display. Just gotta work on getting it to display the correct properties along with it.

Answer (score 2):

The malformed widgets display shown in the query run screenshot is a result of using the graph-notebook extension with JupyterLabs. At the moment, graph-notebook is only supported for use with Jupyter Notebooks, so using it with JupyterLabs may not display the query results as intended.

In addition, depending on how descriptive the Gremlin query results returned are, the graph-notebook extension may not automatically produce graph visualization as part of the output from running the magic query, even if the `path()` step is invoked. In these cases, the `-p` parameter will need to be invoked, and a path pattern specified, to correctly visualize the graph nodes and edges. A corrected version of the query listed might look something like:

```
%%gremlin -p v,oute,inv
g.V("...").outE().inV().path().limit(5)
```

For more information on path patterns, you can check the official AWS documentation:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/notebooks-visualization.html

The Air-Routes-Gremlin sample notebook, included in the graph-notebook package, also has a plethora of example Gremlin query visualization methods, and usage of the various customization options.

https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook/blob/main/src/graph_notebook/notebooks/02-Visualization/Air-Routes-Gremlin.ipynb

These include the `-d` option, which can be used to specify which vertex property value is displayed on the node. By default, graph-notebook's Gremlin visualizer will use each vertex's `T.label` property. If you wanted all of the graph vertices to show the `name` property, for example, instead of the default, you would write the query as:

```
%%gremlin -p v,oute,inv -d name
g.V("...").outE().inV().path().limit(5)
```